# DCM and quaternion orientation transformation

Tags: matlab, transformation, rotations, quaternions, orientation

**BACKGROUND:**
I am using a series of IMUs (Inertial Measurement Units - acc, gyro and magnetometer) to try and estimate human joint angles (e.g knee joint angle). I am using the data from three IMUs and passing the data through an ahrs filter in Matlab to give me a quaternion (or Direction Consine Matrix - DCM) representation of each IMU in the global NED (North, East, Down) frame.

A single IMU is placed arbitrarily on the thigh, and one is placed arbitrarily on the shank. The third IMU is positioned carefully so that the forwards/backwards axes of IMU coordinate system is aligned with the forwards/backwards axes of the body coordinate system (this is placed on the foot, where the foot (body) coordinate system is assumed to be the aligned the shank and thigh). - I hope this all makes sense so far!

**MY QUESTION:** My question is regarding the theory behind the approach I am taking (see methodology heading below). I am new to using IMUs and have very little experience with DCMs and quaternions. I am pretty sure some of my approach is not quite correct, as it does not seem to really matter how out of line with the forward/backward direction my foot/base sensor is - I still seem to get the same joint angle estimation. Does the approach that I am taking make mathematical sense?

**Quick Note:**

$DCM_{bx}$: represents the x component of the DCM for the updated body coordinate system.

$DCM_{ox}$: represents the x component of the DCM for the original coordinate frame (foot sensor).

$q_{tho}$: is the original quaternion representation of the thigh sensor in the global frame.

$q_{thu}$: is the quaternion representation of the thigh sensor aligned with the body frame.

*Please note I have left out shank, and y, z subscript variations for brevity, as the methodology is obviously the same.*

**METHODOLOGY:**

The first step I am taking is to establish a body coordinate system for which the knee joint angle will be estimated. As the foot sensor is aligned in the forward/backward direction, I am assuming that I can first start by transforming the initial orientation to also align with the vertical axes using a DCM. Lets say that the updated body coordinate frame is:

$DCM_b = \begin{bmatrix}DCM_{bx} & DCM_{by} & DCM_{bz}\end{bmatrix}$

where:

$DCM_{bz} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$

$DCM_{by}:$ is the cross product of $DCM_{bz}$ and $DCM_{oz}$ transposed.

$DCM_{bx}:$ is the cross product of $DCM_{by}$ and $DCM_{bz}$ transposed.

I am then converting $DCM_b$ to a quaternion representation $q_b$ so I can use this to transform each of the thigh and shank original sensor orientations (in the global frame) to align with the body coordinate frame (also in the global frame). I am doing this by:

$q_{thu} = q_b \otimes *q_{tho}$

where * represents the quaternion conjugate.

Next, to get the orientation of the thigh and shank sensor at each time instance (k) in the body frame, I am using:

$q_{th(k)} = q_{tho(k)} \otimes q_{thu}$

Finally, the joint angle can be estimated from the relative orientation of the thigh and shank sensor in the body frame by:

$q_{knee(k)} = q_{thu(k)}^- \otimes q_{shu(k)}$

where "-" is the quaternion inverse.

Any thoughts, advice or corrections on the math used in my methodology, or the theory behind the methodology itself would be very much appreciated as I feel like I am getting more and more confused the more I research others' methods online.

Please let me know if you require any further information. Thanks in advance.

Ben

Comment: What does DCM stand for? You say 'quaternion (or DCM)', but based on how you use your DCM entities later on the two definitely aren't identical. For that matter, IMU and NED could both use definitions too — you don't necessarily have to explain every mathematical term to a mathematics audience, but explaining the field-specific terms would be very useful!

Comment: Hi Steven, thank you for your comment and my apologies for brevity. DCM stands for direction cosine matrix, IMU (inertial measurement unit) and NED (north, east down).

Comment: Hi @Ben I'm in a similar boat, getting started with IMUs for measuring joint angles of human limb. Were you able to get it working? If so could you briefly explain your steps? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ben like Olorinlstari I would also like to hear if you find the right solution as I have a similar situation. Hope to hear from you, thanks.

Comment: @Masilila, I'll try and work through this with you. Are you aligning a single axes of one of your sensors with one of your body segment axes? For example, pelvis sensor x axis with pelvis segment anterior/posterior axis?

Comment: Hi @Ben, Thanks for your reply. I do not align the sensors with the segment during placement. I try to align them during a static trail in N-pose where I know the vertical axis of the sensor is aligned with the superior/inferior axis of the segment.

Comment: @Masilila I would recommend aligning either the anterior/posterior or medial/lateral segment axis with an axis of your sensor. That way you know two axes definitively (assuming you are aligning your superior/inferior axis with gravity during the static pose).